# SQL select column when there's more than one of the same name

Tags: sql, call

I have this query

```
select *
from alldistros t1
LEFT join origin t2 on t1.name=t2.name
LEFT join desktop t3 on t2.name=t3.name
LEFT join beginnerdistributions t4 on t3.name=t4.name
```

it add on all my tables. But now when I want to select the name field (which is in all of them) I can't show it. It's just blank when I call it. And I would think so since there's more than 1 columns of the same name.

What can I do to fix this?

Just a plain join won't work, since it removes some of the fields that does not have the properties in the other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'AS' keyword to name a column. For instance:

```
select t1.name AS DistroName, t2.name AS OriginName, t3.name AS DesktopName
from alldistros t1
LEFT join origin t2 on t1.name=t2.name
LEFT join desktop t3 on t2.name=t3.name
LEFT join beginnerdistributions t4 on t3.name=t4.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  t1.name as t1_name,
  t2.name as t2_name,
  t3.name as t3_name
from alldistros t1
LEFT join origin t2 on t1.name=t2.name 
LEFT join desktop t3 on t2.name=t3.name 
LEFT join beginnerdistributions t4 on t3.name=t4.name
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot you can do that!!

Comment: When posting code, highlight the block and hit `CTRL-K` (or press the `{}` button above the editor), to mark it up as code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's Oracle only, but USING can do this for you for ad-hoc queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
JOIN TABLEB USING (NAME)
```

This will only return one NAME column from the SELECT *.