# reading column names from joined query in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

so i've got this long query here:

```
showings = db.execute("SELECT showings.cinema_id, showings.movie_id,\
                       cinemas.name, movies.name FROM showings JOIN\
                       cinemas ON showings.cinema_id=cinemas.id JOIN\
                       movies ON showings.movie_id=movies.id WHERE\
                       showings.id = :id", 
                      {"id": cinema_id}).fetchall()
return render_template("showings.html", showings2=showings2)
```

and then in the template:

```
{% for showing in showings2 %}
   <option value="{{ showing.id }}">
     {{ showing.name }} @{{ showing.name }}
   </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Issue being that due to same column names in two different tables, current template gives back same content twice, that is the value of cinema.name
Any option to bypass it ?

Comment: Related to [SQL select column when there's more than one of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244750/sql-select-column-when-theres-more-than-one-of-the-same-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the columns using aliases:

```
showings = db.execute(
    """SELECT showings.cinema_id
            , showings.movie_id
            , cinemas.name AS cinema_name
            , movies.name AS movie_name
       FROM   showings 
       JOIN   cinemas ON showings.cinema_id=cinemas.id
       JOIN   movies ON showings.movie_id=movies.id
       WHERE  showings.id = :id""", {"id": cinema_id}).fetchall()
```

and use said aliases in the template:

```
<option value="{{ showing.id }}">
    {{ showing.cinema_name }} @ {{ showing.movie_name }}
</option>
```

Comment: sooooo...i knew how to make a double join but didn't know about aliases existence. thanks very much.

Comment: Another option would be to refer to the result columns using their position, but that's more error prone; if you happen to alter your query, the positions may change and the code could possibly break.